# String conversion to time

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want my stored procedure to know how to convert a string which is in the format

```
MM-DD-YYYY (06-23-2008) to the TIMESTAMP(6) format
```

The `TIMESTAMP(6)` format is as follows:

```
03-MAY-15 09.02.44.000000000 PM
```

because data in the table is stored as `timestamp(6)` and I want to use a string to select or modify the appropriate data.

So basically the above date would turn into

```
23-JUNE-08 00.00.00.000000000 PM
```

and then I can loop trough till the end of the day to find the appropriate date

I am very very new to SQL so any guidance/tips are extremely appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP(6)` doesn't have a string format on its own.  It's just a temporal data type that doesn't have any formatting information, only date + time information.

To get a `TIMESTAMP(6)` value from a formatted string, you can use the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function, which will look something like this:

```
select to_timestamp('06-23-2008', 'MM-DD-YYYY') from dual
```

Once you have a `TIMESTAMP(6)` value, then you can choose to convert it to a string and format it any way you choose by using the `TO_CHAR` function.

For example:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('06-23-2008', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

... will return:

```
2008-06-23 00:00:00
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: wow thats a lot of info, let me try this out and i'll have more questions for you for sure

Comment: i was wondering if there would be a way to manipulate 
2008-06-23 00:00:00

to become 

23-JUNE-08 00.00.00.000000000 PM?

Comment: Once you have a timestamp, you can use `to_char` to format it in all kinds of ways.  For instance, what you are asking for would look something like this: `to_char(<your_timestamp>, 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff9')`.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) for all the available formatting options.

Comment: this is VERY strange but my script is this
DECLARE

testdate2 TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN
testdate2 :=sysdate;


TO_CHAR(testdate2, 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff9');

dbms_output.put_line(testdate2);



END;

but i get to_char is not a procedure or is undefined

Comment: I suggest you start a new question if you need more help.  But make sure to read the Help section so that you follow the guidelines for asking questions clearly.  Otherwise, it will get closed like this one.  Remember that this is not some form of live support.  You have to put in the effort and research, and if all fails, present a very clear question that reflects your research and effort.  Good luck.